# Unique constrains on different type

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have two columns like these:

```
A = {1,2,3}; --> Integer[] Type
B = 3; --> Integer Type
```

I would like to UNIQUE constrains this 2 columns of different types.

There is a method to compare all the values ​​of an array with single values in postgres?

P.s (A,B) should be unique

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want `B` not to appear in `A`? Or should`(A, B)` be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot create a unique constraint on array elements table-wide. You can create a check constraint that will ensure that array elements are unique within that array.